# In zsh on mac OS, where is the source of $PATH? I cannot find it in .zshrc

Tags: macos, path, zsh, macos-mojave, oh-my-zsh

When I run `echo $PATH`, my output is:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

But in my `.zshrc`, `$PATH` is commented out:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.  
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

So, where is my `PATH` variable defined at? I am using `oh-my-zsh`, not sure if it has any difference from `zsh`.

Comment: `man zsh` is your friend.   Refer to the section **STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES**.

Answer (score 20):

There are many possibilities, but some are likelier than others.
When starting Zsh, it will source the following files in this order by default:

- `/etc/zsh/zshenv` Used for setting system-wide environment variables.
  This file will always be sourced and cannot be overridden.
- `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv` Used for setting user's environment variables.
  This file will always be sourced.
- `/etc/zsh/zprofile` Used for executing commands at start, will be sourced when starting as a login shell.
- `/etc/profile` This file should be sourced by all Bourne-compatible shells upon login: it sets up $PATH and other environment variables and application-specific (`/etc/profile.d/*.sh`) settings upon login.
- `$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile` Used for executing user's commands at start, will be sourced when starting as a login shell.

  - `$HOME/.profile` is not sourced by zsh.
- `/etc/zsh/zshrc` Used for setting interactive shell configuration and executing commands, will be sourced when starting as an interactive shell.
- `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc` Used for setting user's interactive shell configuration and executing commands, will be sourced when starting as an interactive shell.
- `/etc/zsh/zlogin` Used for executing commands at ending of initial progress, will be sourced when starting as a login shell.
- `$ZDOTDIR/.zlogin` Used for executing user's commands at ending of initial progress, will be sourced when starting as a login shell.

[source : wiki.archlinux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh)

Comment: On macOS, it seems to be `/etc/zprofile`, but there is also `/etc/paths`.

Comment: @AaronFranke and `/etc/paths.d`

Answer (score 9):

It looks as though the original value of `PATH` comes from `/etc/paths`.

Comment: My machine first loaded with /etc/paths.

Comment: none of these answers is where mines saving the exported paths too.. Really bizarre it's so opaque.

Comment: It looks like it will also source files inside `/etc/paths.d`.

Comment: Give the UNIX propeller heads a round of applause!  They can't come up with a simple standard location for PATH variables.  Why didn't this horrible OS die back in 1969!

Comment: Why are we supposed to like .zsh again?